# display google map cordinates won't work in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have google map script to show the map on the page with ajax, i used script of jquery ajax on the separated page, then script of php separated page too,

i wont to display the google map on the main page but the div containing the map with a visibility:none css attribute.

**here is my script of google map in php page:**

```
`<?php
$host="host";
$username="user";
$passowrd="";
$db_name="db";


// Connect to my database and run query
mysql_connect($host,$username,$passowrd) or die("connect to database faild");

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("ünable to connect to database");

$barcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['barcode']);
// select data from tracking table
$query = "SELECT *
               FROM `table`
               WHERE `col` = '$barcode'";
$query2 = mysql_query($queryWatch);

$cor = mysql_fetch_assoc($2);
/* echo $cor['lat'];
echo $cor['lon'];  */
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "var stockholm = new google.maps.LatLng(".$cor['lat']. ",". $cor['lon'].");";
echo "var parliament = new google.maps.LatLng(".$cor['lat']. ",". $cor['lon'].");";
echo "var marker;";
echo "var map;";

echo   "function initialize() {";
echo    "var mapOptions = {";
echo     "zoom: 15,";
echo           "mapTypeId: 

google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,";
echo          "center: stockholm";
echo        "};";

echo         "map = new google.maps.Map

(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),";
echo         "mapOptions);";

echo        "marker = new google.maps.Marker({";
echo          "map:map,";
echo          "draggable:true,";
echo        "animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: parliament
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 

'click', toggleBounce);
      }

      function toggleBounce() {

        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
          marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
          marker.setAnimation

(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
        }";
echo "</script>";
?>`
```

**here is the script of ajax:**

```
function get() {
    $.post('fetch-map.php', {barcode: searchBarcode.barcode.value},
    function(output) {
        $('#mapContainer').html(output).show();
    });
}
```

again the css attribute of the map container is visibility:none;
but the map won't work ...
is there something i miss ...???
help will be appreciated

Comment: It would be more convenient for you if you used the [heredoc](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to output your js.

Answer (score 0):

If all your JS has been posted then you are not calling the `initialize()` function. Try adding this at the end:

```
[..rest of code]
  echo "initialize();"
  echo "</script>";
```